# Write the content of two Excel files in a third one

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to vba programming and I would like to know what is the best method to do the following operation : read data from two Excel files (from a particular column of each file) and write this data in a third Excel file, writing the data contained in the first file first then the data contained in the second file. The figure below illustrates what I want to do :

[image]

How can I do that on click on a command button, without opening the two first files (I mean I don't want the user to see them).

Comment: If you'll strictly impose not to open the file, you can try using [`ADO (Active Data Objects)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676795(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make so

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= "c:\myfile\FILE1.xls"FILE1.xls"
Workbooks.Open Filename:= "c:\myfile\FILE2.xls"
```

After you open the FILE1.xls and FILE.xls you can create or open FILE3.xls,
in this case we create the FILE3.xls

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
```

After this you read the data in FILE1.xls and FILE2.xls, you can read with WHILE or other LOOP or you read with COPY and PASTE data in new file. 
In this case we see the LOOP strategy.

```
Dim i as Integer
Dim value as String
i=0
value = value = Workbooks("FILE1.xls").Worksheets("sheet1")..Range("B:B").Cells(i, 1) 


Workbooks("FILE1.xls").Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
while value <> ""

   Workbooks("FILE1.xls").Worksheets(2).Range("A:A").Cells(i, 1) = value    

  value = value = Workbooks("FILE1.xls").Worksheets("sheet1")..Range("B:B").Cells(i, 1) 

Wend
```

Repeat ste for "FILE2.xls" read data and write in "FILE3.xls"
and at the and you close

```
 wb.SaveAs "c:\myfile\"FILE3.xls""
 wb.Close
```

And close the read data file

```
Workbooks("FILE1.xls").Close
Workbooks("FILE2.xls").Close
```